# How to echo databse value to input feild in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, echo, textfield

I'm working on this MySQL table and I want to display data inside text field. I can fetch data in to div and i need it inside text field. Any thoughts.??
Here is my code to put inside text field and it wont work .. :(

```
echo "<td width='517'>""<input type='text' value='. $row['firstName'] .'/>" "</td>";
```

Comment: What's with the quotes in quotes? If you need them, escape them. `\"`

Comment: No white spaces here: `'. $row['firstName'] .'`

Comment: Please post the SELECT and php strings also

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
echo "<td width='517'><input type='text' value='".$row['firstName']."'/></td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are three ways you can do this:

**Using single quotes**

```
echo '<td width="517"><input type="text" value="'. $row['firstName'] . '"/></td>';
```

**Using double quotes**

```
echo "<td width=\"517\"><input type=\"text\" value=\"$row[firstName]\"/></td>";
```

**Not using quotes**

```
<td width="517"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['firstName'] ?>"/></td>
```